# Paste and split long number to multiple input

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I am trying to develop a multiple-input form in which I paste a long number that automatically splits into each input by 2 numbers each.

Everything works fine until the user pastes a number of only 5 digits such as `45896` and instead of reporting an error, another number is created in the first input. I can't understand how the form leaves white space, which it then fills by inventing a number, in the first input instead of leaving a blank space on the last input.

In addition I developed `else if (input.value.length !== 2 ) input.value = '0' + input.value;` to add a `0` in front of the number if the input has only one number but only if the user types in numbers.

I would like the paste function to show an error if one of the inputs contains less than 2 digits and that when pasting a number less than 6 digits long the white space remains on the last input and not on the first.

Is there something wrong in my code  or should I improve it to reach my goal?

```html
<style>
.circle input {
  border-radius: 999px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="tkt_1">
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="tel" min="1" max="99" minlength="2" maxlength="2" oninput="if((this.value.length) > 2) {this.value = this.value.substring(0, 2);}" onchange="handleChange(this);" placeholder="00" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="tel" min="1" max="99" minlength="2" maxlength="2" oninput="if((this.value.length) > 2) {this.value = this.value.substring(0, 2);}" onchange="handleChange(this);" placeholder="00" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="tel" min="1" max="99" minlength="2" maxlength="2" oninput="if((this.value.length) > 2) {this.value = this.value.substring(0, 2);}" onchange="handleChange(this);" placeholder="00" />
  </div>
</form>

<script>
// Paste numbers from clipboard in multiple input 
document.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
    // if the target is a text input
    if (e.target.type === "tel") {
        var data = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        // split clipboard text into single characters
        data = data.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/g);

        // find all other text inputs
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=tel]"), (node, index) => {
            // And set input value to the relative character
            node.value = data[ index ] ?? "";

        });
    }
});

// Validation
function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value < 0) input.value = "";
    else if (input.value.length !== 2 ) input.value = '0' + input.value;
    else if (input.value < 0.9 || input.value > 99 || input.value.length === 1 || input.value.length === 0) {
        input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        return false;
    } else {
        input.style.backgroundColor = '';
        return true;
    }
}

// Input only Numbers 
$('.circle input').keypress(function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var charCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    // FireFox key Del - Supr - Up - Down - Left - Right
    if (event.key !== undefined && event.charCode === 0) {
        return;
    }
    //Only Num
    if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    //Num and letters
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: JS note: that `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=tel]")` yields an object that comes with a `.forEach` function. But it's the `node.value = data[ index ] ||= ""; node.value = data[ index ];` part that's super questionable. What did  you intend that line to do? (On which note: put your script in its own file, and load it with `<script src="myfile.js" async defer></script>`, so that you can load that .js in your code editor and get proper warnings, hints, and formatting)

Comment: Thanks @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans for your answer.
That line split the copied number from the clipboard to each input in 2 digits each one. 'node.value = data[ index ] ||= "";' removes 'undefined' in the input, which remains empty 'Firefox compatibility'.
I actually don't know if the Paste script is correct but it seems working fine. Do you know a way to perform it better?

Comment: yeah, that's `a = b ?? "something else"` in modern JS, using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). There is no reason to double-assign node.value

Comment: Your form takes value values of "fu", "rr", "ey" to deal with

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I tried modifying the code as you suggested, but the problem was not solved. Pasting a 5-digit number from the clipboard results in a white space in the first input and not the last.
I found this script in another post on Stackoverflow and it seemed to fit my project. I am not very skilled in JS, so I hope I got it right.

Comment: Paste "e12345" in and you can see it creates "1e", "23", "45" to give a clue here

Comment: On these input are allowed only numbers without 'e' or other signs. They are just 3 inputs for 2 digits each. I tried following your suggestion but I get: '1 ', '23', '45'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue described with the splitting was happening due to the regex split which was leaving the first input single rather than the last input.

Also, another issue is that `onchange` is not triggered by pasting values so the `handleChange` function is never called on pasting the values.

```html
<style>
.circle input {
  border-radius: 999px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="tkt_1">
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="tel" value="00" min="0" minlength="2" maxlength="2" oninput="if((this.value.length) > 2) {this.value = this.value.substring(0, 2);}" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="tel" value="00" min="0" minlength="2" maxlength="2" oninput="if((this.value.length) > 2) {this.value = this.value.substring(0, 2);}" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="tel" value="00" min="0" minlength="2" maxlength="2" oninput="if((this.value.length) > 2) {this.value = this.value.substring(0, 2);}" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
  </div>
</form>

<script>
// Paste numbers from clipboard in multiple input 
document.addEventListener("paste", function (e) {
    // if the target is a text input
    if (e.target.type === "tel") {
        var data = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        // split clipboard text into single characters
        data = data.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        // Modified approach to split data into pairs
        var pairs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2) {
            pairs.push(data.slice(i, i + 2));
        }
        data = pairs;

        // find all other text inputs
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=tel]"), (node, index) => {
            // And set input value to the relative character
            node.value = data[ index ] ?? "";
            handleChange(node); //Added to trigger validation rules for pasted data

        });
    }
});

// Validation
function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value < 0) input.value = "";
    else if (input.value.length !== 2 ) input.value = '0' + input.value;
    else if (input.value < 0.9 || input.value > 99 || input.value.length === 1 || input.value.length === 0) {
        input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        return false;
    } else {
        input.style.backgroundColor = '';
        return true;
    }
}

var pasteModifier = false; // Store if control or the meta key is pressed state
// Need to handle the paste functionality
$('.circle input').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey){
        pasteModifier = true;
    }
});
$('.circle input').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey){
        pasteModifier = false;
    }
});
// Input only Numbers 
$('.circle input').keypress(function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var charCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    // FireFox key Del - Supr - Up - Down - Left - Right
    if (event.key !== undefined && event.charCode === 0) {
        return;
    }
    // Handle paste command
    if (charCode == 118 && pasteModifier){
      return;
    }
    //Only Num
    else if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    //Num and letters
    else if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

I have modified the code to use a regular slicing method to split the data string into 2 digits each and leave a single in the last input if applicable. The `handleChange` function is also triggered within the loop setting the value for each input so it can act on the pasted data.

Currently if you paste 5 digits, it does not give an error but appends a 0 at the start of the last input due to the rule set up in the `handleChange` function.

If you remove this line

```
else if (input.value.length !== 2 ) input.value = '0' + input.value;
```

you will encounter the red error instead.

In some browsers including Safari keypress events take higher precedence than the paste commands leading to breaking the paste functionality in this case.

Also, `keypress` only sees the visible key triggers, unlike `keydown` and `keyup`. So I have included the additional `keydown` and `keyup` event handlers to check if the pressed key is the `Meta` key for Mac or `Ctrl` key for Windows and keep that stored as a state in the `pasteModifier` variable.

This can then be a condition in the `keypress` handler, where if the `Meta or Ctrl` key is still pressed (`keyup` did not fire) and then a `V` is pressed, it returns as paste handler need not do anything.

Comment: Thank you very much @deepanshu223! This is what I was struggling with for days and your explanation taught me a lot. Yes, you're right, I didn't think of including handleChange in the paste function as well and I probably wouldn't have succeeded.
The input should only allow numbers and the project includes the script I just integrated in my first post. Testing it on Safari, it blocks the paste function operated by the keyboard (ctrl+v). Is there some conflict between the various regexes or some other error?

Comment: @Freddan Glad my answer helped.
I have heard of Safari restricting some paste functionality though I tested it on my MacBook Safari, and the example I have posted seems to work fine.
Could you detail more on what is the issue and on which device?

Comment: I can't thank you enough @deepanshu223 !
The solution you posted still allows user to enter letters and other characters when the user types from the keyboard because I did not included the script in the beginning. I finished including it on my first post so now you can test it on Safari and it turns out that the block for only numbers on keypress breaks the paste function.

Comment: @Freddan I have updated the code for handling this issue and added an explanation.
As you may see, the issue isn't in the code but in how the browser handles events.

Comment: You are a master! The way you handled the whole code was too complicated for my limited knowledge of JS. So you wrote the code in full, including all the elements because Safari needs 'the long version', isn't it? Thanks a lot again for everything, I go digging deeper on JS

Comment: @Freddan hahaha, yes, browsers doing things differently, just come back to haunt you every now and then.  Good luck with your journey in JS!